# delete a particular element from a single linked list (no access to header of list)

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I need to delete an element from linked list where address of that element is given.Something like this

1->2->3->4->5
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5  where a1,a2..a5 are addresses of elements 1,2 ..5 respectively.
sum1 just says delete(a3) N since I have no access to header of given list.
I cant traverse the whole linked list and compare the address with the asked address.

Question is how I delete a particular element from the given list with no other information given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic interview question.

You don't delete that element, but copy the next element into it:

So you do:

- a3 = a4
- delete a4

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you're right, no need to copy all of them. Thanks.

Comment: B. @Luchian you should also be aware your way won't work if this is the last element.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel if it's the last element, next is null. So you copy null into it. Anyway, his example was with the middle element.

Comment: how can you copy the value of a null? and what exactly the delete will do to the null. trust me, it's not working for the last element. and yes, for his example it will work but it's good to know it can't work always.

Comment: But this method will fail miserably if the list is heterogeneous. (such as "smart union")

Answer (score 1):

this can only work if you don't receive the last value of the list:

```
void delete(pointerType x)
{
if (x->next == null) return;//this algorithm won't work

//in any other case:
x->value = x->next->value;
pointerType toDelete = x->next;
x->next = x->next->next;
delete toDelete;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the following two reasons:

- You don't have access to 2->next. This means you can't just simply delete element 3.
- Treating the list like an array is a bad idea provided that your list is VERY long.

You have to work on a local scale. My solution in words is:

1. assign a4 to a3 (so 2->next is a4 and the new a3->next = a5).
2. delete the old a4

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
as you don't have header of list you can't traverse list
but you are provided with node to delete
so you can copy next node into it and delete next node

suppose a1 -> to delete
if(a1 && a1->next)
{
   a1=a2;
delete a1;
} 
else if(a1)
{
   delete a1;
}
else
 return NULL;
```